# lagged regression equation properties

Tags: econometrics, regression, statistics

consider this equation 1: \begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
C_{t} = \beta_{1} + \lambda   C_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}
\end{equation}
If the error term is independently and identically distributed (iid) with mean 0 and
constant variance and \begin{equation} \label{eq:2}
E(\epsilon_{t}\mid C_{t-1}) = 0
\end{equation}
i.e., the error is not correlated with  \begin{equation}C_{t-1})\end{equation}
Is the OLS estimator of the coefficients in equation 1
unbiased and consistent under this new error specification? Why?

My answer: I would assume unbiased and consistent because the expectation of the errors and the lagged variable = 0 ?
Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

OLS is consistent but biased. For consistency, we need $Cov(\epsilon_t, C_{t-1})=0$. The condition, $E[\epsilon_t|C_{t-1}]=0$ is sufficient for the covariance to be 0.

For unbiasedness, we need $E[\epsilon_t|C]=0$ where $C$ is the vector of $C_t$ at all time periods.

Comment: Just a follow up: Consider the following regression equation (* )    \begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
C_{t} = \beta_{1} + \lambda   C_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}
\end{equation}
and let \begin{equation} \label{eq:3}
\epsilon_{t} = \rho\epsilon_{t-1} + u_{t}
\end{equation} where the error component \begin{equation} u_{t}\end{equation} is iid with mean 0 and constant
variance, and \begin{equation} \label{eq:4}
E(u_{t}\mid   C_{t-1},\epsilon_{t-1}) = 0
\end{equation}
Is the OLS estimator of the coefficients in (*)
unbiased and consistent under this error specification? Why?

Comment: OLS will be biased for the same reason, although it may be consistent. I responded on your other question.